# Changing origin for circle in JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm using the JPanel and JFrame to animate an example of something called Circle Packing, which essentially is just filling an object with continuously growing circles to fill the object with circles of different sizes.

I've been able to animate an arraylist of circle objects, but they grow in a way that is not desirable for my project. A circle growing, according to me, is a fixed point P from which a circle with radius R around it is created, and it expands solely by the R increasing. JPanel does not act this way. It changes the x and y positions as well, which I do not understand.

This is my repaint:

```
public void repaint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(new Color(125, 0, 100));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    g.setColor(new Color(255, 165, 0));

    Circle myCircle = new Circle(rand.nextInt(500), rand.nextInt(500), 1);
    circles.add(myCircle);

    for (Circle c : circles) {
        int newx = (int) c.getX();
        int newy = (int) c.getY();
        int newsize = (int) c.getSize();

        c.grow();
        c.growth(); // These are the growing functions
        c.Edges();
        g.drawOval(newx, newy, newsize, newsize);
    }
}
```

and my grow, growth and Edges are to check for cases where the circles touches the sides of the screen.

Please edit my question to a more appropriate title if necessary, I'm still new to S.O.

Comment: `Circle myCircle = new Circle(rand.nextInt(500), rand.nextInt(500), 1);` you do realize that the random numbers are between 0 and 500? i think that could be your problem

Comment: How is your `repaint` (change that name, it is confusing) method called? What `grow()` and `growth()` do?

Comment: Renamed repaint to construct, which is called in my extended JPanel class called Render, in the paintComponent method. 

The circle object has a boolean growing which is true; grow, growth and Edges control that variable for different cases. While it is true: this.size++;

Comment: did you change the creation of the `Circle` objects, to alway use the same values and not random ones?

Comment: Even if I instead of using the arraylist for creation, and create one circle in the middle of the screen, this weird behaviour still persists.

Answer (score 0):

> A circle growing, according to me, is a fixed point P from which a circle with radius R around it is created, and it expands solely by the R increasing

Maybe, but you didn't write the `Graphics` API. So your code needs to work based on the methods of the API.

> It changes the x and y positions as well, which I do not understand.

Read the API for the drawOval(...) method to understand how it works. Don't assume how it works.

The method works by specifying the top/left x/y point, not the center point.

So if the radius increases, the x/y values must decrease if you want the center point to remain constant. So you need to fix your grow logic.

> I'm using the JPanel and JFrame to animate an example of something called Circle Packing,

Also, don't generate random values in a painting method. You can't control when the component will be repainted so the values can change unexpectedly. That is don't change the state of an object in a painting method.

So you need a method to "grow" each circle (which is separate from your painting code). This method will adjust the radius and x/y location of each object in the Array. Then you invoke repaint() on the panel. The painting code will then just iterate through the Array and paint the current state of each object in the array.